# Code mistake on "Getting started with Tensorflow" Section "A custom model"

Tags: tensorflow

In [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started), at the bottom of the page in Section "A custom model"...after

```
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x": x_train}, y_train, 4, num_epochs=1000)
```

shouldn't there be this line of code?

```
eval_input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x":x_eval}, y_eval, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `eval_input_fn` is missing, this issue has been fixed in the latest version doc on github, please checkout https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/docs_src/get_started/get_started.md#a-custom-model